# Unable To Mass-Set A Background Color For A Class

Tags: javascript, css, class, background-color

I'm creating an HTML pixel art canvas made out of a table made up of lots of different divs, and they all have the same class: "pixel." I want to include a clear button so that I can completely wipe the slate clean, but to do so, I'd have to change the background color of the class, because there's no way I'm setting an ID for all four hundred of those pixels. Can someone tell me why something like this won't work and suggest an alternative method?

```
function clearCanvas() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("pixel").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array which has no style attribute

Comment: @E.Sundin Ah, thank you. I did a for loop to change each one in the array and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cause `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection and that is just a weird form of an array. Therefore you cant set a style on it. However you could iterate over all elements and set their style:

```
  const pixels = document.getElementsByClassName("pixel");

  for(const pixel of pixels)
     pixel.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a list which you can iterate and apply the styling to each matched element.

```
for(let el of document.getElementsByClassName("pixel")) el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```